# How to add annotation to map from another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I want to create an annotation using a button in the `CreateDetailsViewController` to add it on the `MapViewController`.

The code below works fine when I type it into the `viewDidLoad` on the MapView. But I could not figure out how to implement it from one screen to another.

I am very new to programming so please consider this while answering. Thanks!

---

```
  //Button I want to create the annotation with in `CreateDetailsViewControllwer` :

 @IBAction func publishButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
        
        func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            
            let MapVC = segue.destination as! MapViewController
            
            var london = MKPointAnnotation()
            london.title = "London"
            london.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.508530, -0.076132)
            MapVC.mapView.addAnnotation(london)
            
            func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
                guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else {return nil}
                
                let identifier = "Annotation"
                var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
                
                if annotationView == nil {
                    annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                    annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
                } else {
                    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
                }
                
                 return annotationView
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Selen you need to use Notification Center

Notification Center: You can broadcast data from one of your view controller to another.

```
 @IBAction func publishButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pin koy"), object: nil)
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
   
}
```

Then use this code to where you want the create annotation(I think it is mapViewController)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pinleme), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "pin koy"), object: nil)
}
```

And it is the func for your annotation;

```
@objc func pinleme() {
    let annotation= MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.508530, -0.076132)

    annotation.title = "London"
    
    mapKit.addAnnotation(annotation)

    //anlamadıysan inst-fburakk19
}
```

Comment: Thank you Burak! This saved me so much time and energy.